# how to do this format conversion of array elements in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

i created an array from a json from server whose NSLOG shows this -

```
(
        (
        "/api/v1/user/75/"
    ),
        (
        "/api/v1/user/86/"
    ),
        (
        "/api/v1/user/65/"
    ),
        (
        "/api/v1/user/70/"
    ),
        (
        "/api/v1/user/2/"
    )
)
```

how can i convert elements of the array so that i get this NSLOG of the modified array..

```
(
    "/api/v1/user/75/",
    "/api/v1/user/86/",
    "/api/v1/user/65/",
    "/api/v1/user/70/",
    "/api/v1/user/2/"
)
```

in case you are wondering why i need this its because in next stage i am having trouble filtering another array using this array elements with nspredicate . The later format doesn't give error

Comment: how you got  first array. this format is **invalid**.

Comment: Looks like your `NSArray` elements are also `NSArray`s with single element of `NSString` type. try to convert the type of first array elements to `NSString`

Comment: One line for this is: `NSArray *flattenedArray = [array valueForKeyPath: @"@unionOfArrays.self"];` - flattening,

Comment: this is worked for me . since its shorter i tried this first.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your description you have an NSArray which holds NSArray objects (in which the NSStrings are located). To convert it to a NSArray of NSStrings you would have to flatten it. Below is the example method that can be used for flattening:

```
- (NSArray*)flatten:(NSArray*)array {
    NSMutableArray* flattenedArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[array count]];

    for (id element in array) {
        if ([element isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
            [flattenedArray addObjectsFromArray:[self flatten:element]];
        }
        else {
            [flattenedArray addObject:element];
        }
    }

    return flattenedArray;
}
```